# Lex / Yacc : Same regex for two terminal symbols

Tags: parsing, pattern-matching, yacc, lex

I'm working on a parser and I need to be able to have two distinct symbols with the same regex.

But, my parser can not work since as the two regex are identical, the lexer will always match the first and the wrong symbol may be returned and cause the parsing to fail.

I cannot merge the two symbols into a single one and rely on the semantic analysis because my grammar will become ambigous because I have rules like :

```
a : c a
  | c

b : d b
  | d
```

With a and b the symbols with the same regex.
If i merge them into a single symbol, let's say `e`, this might produce rules like :

```
e -> c e -> c d e -> ...
```

And rules containing `c` symbol and those with `d` symbol have to be kept separated.

That's why I prefer keeping `a` and `b` distinct and trying to find a way to have to symbols matching the same regex.

- Is there any solution to prevent lex to stop on a rule in particular so that it can match eventual other further regex and let the grammar decide which one should be used ?
- Maybe my approach is wrong, then how should I rethink my grammar ?

Answer (score 2):

If there is no conflict possible, then there is no need to have two symbols. The parser will interpret the token correctly.

If you require different semantic values for the different contexts, the semantic action can be moved to the parser, using two different unit rules with the same right-hand side. For example:

#### scanner.l

```
{sym}     { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return SYM; }
```

#### parser.y

```
sym1      SYM { $$ = semval1($1); free($1); }
sym2      SYM { $$ = semval2($1); free($1); }
```

Comment: Actually, there will be conflicts if I use a single symbol, that's why I am willing to use two different ones. Using two distinct symbols also simplifies a lot the parser since there is no need for further semantic checking.

Comment: @ibi0tux: in your question you say "These symbols are used in completely different parts of the grammar and no conflict is possible." Now you seem to be contradicting yourself.

Comment: Well, I think my question wasn't really clear. I'm editing it.

Comment: @ibi0tux: in your edit, `a` and `b`  seem to be both terminals and non-terminals. Perhaps it would be better to use a real MCVE showing a real parser conflict. I am not saying you should merge non-terminals.